# How to update GridView Items in Android

Tags: android, gridview, adapter

I am using an imageview and a progressbar as each child items of a gridview(Each GridView item contains an imageview and a progressbar) where progressbar is hidden. Each progressbar is visible when tap on grid item.

At first a loading image is shown in the imageview and it is updated by using downloaded images.

My problem is, when the user tap on grid item where image is loading image(Downloading is in progress)

the progressbar become visible.But the progressbar become invisible when invoking **notifyDataSetChanged()**  to update the image.

**How can i keep the state of progressbar even if the image is updated ?**

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`notifyDataSetChanged()` causes the `GridView` to be reloaded. So you have to handle if the progress bar to be visible in your adapter's `getView()` method.

Comment: No.I want to make the progressbar visible only when the user tap on grid item

Comment: You should remember which cell is been tapping, then in the adapter's getView() method, if the cell is been tapping, make progress bar to be visible.